# Run as Java Application has different result from Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, debugging, proxy, spring-boot

It is said the Spring Boot App can be run as Java Application, especially when I use JRebel to hot deploy in debug my app.

Today I found a difference between run as Java App and Spring Boot App, is this a bug in Run as Java App for Spring Boot App?

There is a application.properties in my project, I defined proxyHost and proxyPort when I am in company, but at home I will comment it. If I run as Java App, the proxy data is still used though there is no any this settings in application.properties file. When I run as Spring Boot App, that is ok without problem.

My two questions:
1. Why they have different result run as Java or Spring Boot App?
2. Where proxy data is saved when run as Java App?

I can provide any logs if needed.

Comment: `application.properties` is a static resource. Please, ensure you recompile your application before running the test at home

Comment: I clean and recompile and reinstall a lot of times:( I also delete whole target folder then install again, but it is the same! Now I found reason because JRebel! Run as Java with JRebel will use my proxy property! Run as Java without JRbel or Run as Spring Boot are good without problems! By the way, I copied all files except target folder from company after proxy to home without proxy.

Comment: Please report this problem to support@zeroturnaround.com and it'll be fixed.

Comment: Are you sure you you didn't configure the proxy host/proxy port in your Run configuration perhaps?